# how passing props between component using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've retrieved datas from my database to the *Recipes component*. now, I'm trying to pass those datas into the *RecipeList component*. However, I got just the bullet points into the *RecipeList component* and for some reason the *Recipes component* return only the element " title = {recipe.title} "
I'm just starting out programming. I would be pleased if someone can help me.

### Recipes

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import RecipeList from '../pages/espaceUser/RecipeList'

export default function Recipes(props) {

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])

    const [test] = useState("text")




    useEffect(() => {

        const id = props.match.params.id

        const getRecipes = async () => {
            const url = `http://localhost:8000/user/recipes/${id}`  
            const result = await axios.get(url)

                setRecipes(result.data)
                console.log('test', result.data);
            }


            getRecipes()

    },[])

    return (

        <div>


            {recipes.map(recipe => (
            <RecipeList
            key={recipe.id}
            title={recipe.title}
            materiel={recipe.materiel}
            ingredient={recipe.ingredient}/>

            ))}

        </div>
    )
}
```

### RecipeList

```
import React from 'react'

export default function RecipeList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>{props.title}</li>
                <li>{props.materiel}</li>
                <li>{props.ingredient}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You have fetched the data correctly and saved in the state but cannot read it as props or what? Can you console.log the props in the RecipeList ?

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data that comes from that API call? Your code looks fine, but maybe the data items don't have an `id`, `materiel` or `ingredient` property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it is not a problem with the syntax or structure of your code, if it's rendering the title at least it means that everything is working fine. I would suggest looking at react dev tools in chrome and check out if the components have all the props they are supposed to have